# Elevator code for a game called ROBLOX

Tags: game, lua

Are there any ways I could improve speed and less code? The elevator that uses this script works fine. Could anything be better?

```
print(" Teknikk xPower 9700 PRE DEV V1 Intialised")


-- Develoment sample, May have functions added or removed. --
local Floor = script.Parent.Floor
local Floors = script.Parent.Floors
local FireLock = false
local Alarm = false
local Open = false
local Closed = true
local IsOpening = false
local IsClosing = false
local Moving = false
local Busy = false
local Locked = false
local DoorSpeed = 0.00001
local MotorStartSpeed = 0.13
local MotorStopSpeed = 0.13
local MotorSpeed = 12
local MotorCurrentSpeed = 8
local MoveDirection = "None"
local CallDirection = "None"
local FloorIndicatorOffset = 6
local LevelOffset = 3
local TargetFloor = 0
local TotalFloors = 0
local Car = script.Parent.Car.Control
local duck = false
local WaitCall = false
local CallQuene = {}

local CardLock = true
local CardNumber = {0,1}
local LockedFloors = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

function ProcessCall(xFloor, xDest)
    if TargetFloor == 0 and xFloor ~= xDest then
        if xDest > xFloor then
            TargetFloor = xDest
            Car.DirectionalIndicator.Decal.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=119917350"
            Start("Up")
        end
        if xDest < xFloor then
            TargetFloor = xDest
            Car.DirectionalIndicator.Decal.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=119917359"
            Start("Down")   
        end 
    end
end


function Start(xDirection)
Busy = true
if Open or IsOpening then
repeat DoorClose(Floor.Value) wait(0.1) until Closed == true and IsOpening == false
end
Moving = true
-- Some code for just 1 floor up, not too fast --
    if (Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TargetFloor).FloorLevel.Position - script.Parent.Car.Control.FloorLevel.Position).Magnitude < 14 then
        MotorCurrentSpeed = 5
        MotorStopSpeed = 0.05
        LevelOffset = 5
    else
        MotorCurrentSpeed = MotorSpeed
        MotorStopSpeed = 0.05
        LevelOffset = 6.5
    end
Car.Platform.BodyPosition.P = 0
Car.Platform.BodyPosition.D = 0
Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.P = 5000      
    if xDirection == "Up" then
        MoveDirection = "Up"
        for i = 0, MotorCurrentSpeed, 1 do
            Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.velocity = Vector3.new(0,i,0)
            wait(MotorStartSpeed)
        end
    end
    if xDirection == "Down" then
        MoveDirection = "Down"
        for i = 0, MotorCurrentSpeed, 1 do
            Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.velocity = Vector3.new(0,-i,0)
            wait(MotorStartSpeed)
        end
    end
end

function Stop(TF)
if TargetFloor ~= TF then return end

Btn(TargetFloor,0)
Car.DirectionalIndicator.Decal.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=0"
FPos = script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).FloorLevel.Position.Y
Car.Platform.BodyPosition.position = Vector3.new(Car.Platform.BodyPosition.position.X,FPos,Car.Platform.BodyPosition.position.Z)
Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.P = 0
Car.Platform.BodyPosition.P = 10000
Car.Platform.BodyPosition.D = 6000
Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
repeat 
print((script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).FloorLevel.Position - script.Parent.Car.Control.FloorLevel.Position).Magnitude) 
wait(0.1) 
until (script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).FloorLevel.Position - script.Parent.Car.Control.FloorLevel.Position).Magnitude < 0.4
wait(1)
TargetFloor = 0
if Floor.Value == TotalFloors then
    MoveDirection = "Down"

end
if Floor.Value == 1 then
    MoveDirection = "Up"
end
DirInd(TF,MoveDirection)
Moving = false
wait(1)
DoorOpen(TF)
print("Waiting 4 sec before delete and check")
Quene(TF,"Remove")
Busy = false
wait(4)
Quene(0,"Check")
end

function DoorOpen(TF)
if Closed and not IsOpening and TF ~= nil and not Moving  then
IsOpening = true

if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen") ~= nil then
    Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Lime green")
end
if MoveDirection == "Up" then
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding.Pitch = 0.5
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding:Play()
end
if MoveDirection == "Down" then
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding.Pitch = 0.5
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding:Play()
    wait(0.5)
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding.Pitch = 0.3
    Car.FloorIndicator.Ding:Play()
end
CarRight = script.Parent.Car.Control.DoorRight
CarLeft = script.Parent.Car.Control.DoorLeft
DoorRight = script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).DoorRight
DoorLeft = script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).DoorLeft
if DoorRight == nil and DoorLeft == nil then print("Cant open doors, No shaft doors") return end
CarRight.Anchored = true
CarLeft.Anchored = true
for i=0, 51 do
CarRight.CFrame = CarRight.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, 0.05)
CarLeft.CFrame = CarLeft.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -0.05)
DoorRight.CFrame = DoorRight.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, 0.05)
DoorLeft.CFrame = DoorLeft.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -0.05)
wait(DoorSpeed)
end
CarRight.Anchored = true
CarLeft.Anchored = true
Closed = false
Open = true
if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen") ~= nil then
    Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Institutional white")
end
IsOpening = false
end
end

function DoorClose(TF)
if Open and not IsClosing and TF ~= nil and not Moving then
IsClosing = true
DirInd(TF,"None")
if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose") ~= nil then
Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Lime green")
end
CarRight = script.Parent.Car.Control.DoorRight
CarLeft = script.Parent.Car.Control.DoorLeft
DoorRight = script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).DoorRight
DoorLeft = script.Parent.Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..TF).DoorLeft
if DoorRight == nil and DoorLeft == nil then print("Cant open doors, No shaft doors") return end
CarRight.Anchored = true
CarLeft.Anchored = true
for i=0, 51 do
CarRight.CFrame = CarRight.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -0.05)
CarLeft.CFrame = CarLeft.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, 0.05)
DoorRight.CFrame = DoorRight.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -0.05)
DoorLeft.CFrame = DoorLeft.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, 0.05)
wait(DoorSpeed)
end
CarRight.Anchored = false
CarLeft.Anchored = false
Closed = true
Open = false
if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose") ~= nil then
Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Institutional white")
end
IsClosing = false
end
end

function Btn(xFloor,xMode)
    local xCar = Car.FloorBtn:FindFirstChild("F"..xFloor)
    local xCall = Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..xFloor):FindFirstChild("CallButton")
    local xDual = script.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild("CallFloor")
    if xMode == 1 then
        if xCar ~= nil then
            xCar.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
        end
        if xCall ~= nil then
            xCall.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
        end
        if xDual ~= nil then
            if xDual:FindFirstChild("F"..xFloor) ~= nil then
                xDual:FindFirstChild("F"..xFloor).CallButton.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
            end
        end
    end
    if xMode == 0 then
        if xCar ~= nil then
            xCar.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Institutional white")
        end
        if xCall ~= nil then
            xCall.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Institutional white")
        end
        if xDual ~= nil then
            if xDual:FindFirstChild("F"..xFloor) ~= nil then
                xDual:FindFirstChild("F"..xFloor).CallButton.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Institutional white")
            end
        end
    end
end


function DirInd(xFloor,xDir)
    local Dup = Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..xFloor):FindFirstChild("DirIndUp")
    local Ddn = Floors:FindFirstChild("Floor"..xFloor):FindFirstChild("DirIndDown")
    if xDir == "Up" then
            Dup.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright green")
    end
    if xDir == "Down" then
            Ddn.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
    end

    if xDir == "None" then
            Dup.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
            Ddn.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
    end
end


function Quene(xFloor,Mode,isCall)
    if Mode == "Check" then
        for i = 1, #CallQuene do
            if CallQuene[i] ~= nil then
                ProcessCall(Floor.Value, CallQuene[i])
            end
        end

    end
    if Mode == "Add" then
        Btn(xFloor,1)
        local IgnoreCall = false

        if isCall ~= true then
        for i = 1, #LockedFloors do
            if LockedFloors[i] == xFloor then
                print("Call is in Lock list.")
                if CardLock then
                    IgnoreCall = true
                end
            end

        end
        end

        for i = 1, #CallQuene do
            if CallQuene[i] == xFloor then
                print("Call exist, Not adding floor: "..CallQuene[i])
                IgnoreCall = true

            end

        end



        if not IgnoreCall and xFloor ~= Floor.Value and not Locked or not IgnoreCall and xFloor ~= Floor.Value and xFloor == 1  then
            table.insert(CallQuene,xFloor)
            print("Floor added, Value: "..xFloor)
            Btn(xFloor,1)       
            if not Busy then Quene(0,"Check") end
        else
            if xFloor == Floor.Value and not Locked or IgnoreCall then
            wait(0.2)
            Btn(xFloor,0)
            end
            if Locked then
            wait(0.2)
            Btn(xFloor,0)
            end
        end

    end

    if Mode == "Remove" then

            for i = 1, #CallQuene do
                if CallQuene[i] == xFloor then
                print("Removed: "..CallQuene[i])
                    table.remove(CallQuene,i)
                end
            end
            Btn(xFloor,"Off")
    end
end


function FireMode(Player)
        if not FireLock then
            Car.LockInd.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
            Floors.Floor1:FindFirstChild("FireService").Key.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=121879581"
            FireLock = true
            Locked = true
                for i = 1, #CallQuene do
                    print("Removed: "..CallQuene[i])
                    table.remove(CallQuene,i)
                end
                Car.DirectionalIndicator.Decal.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=0"
                if Floor.Value ~= 1 then
                    DoorClose(Floor.Value)
                    Moving = true
                    Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.P = 2560
                    Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
                    TargetFloor = 1
                    MoveDirection = "Down"
                    wait(1)
                    Car.Platform.BodyVelocity.velocity = Vector3.new(0,-6,0)
                end
            elseif FireLock then
                Car.LockInd.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
                Floors.Floor1:FindFirstChild("FireService").Key.Texture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=121879579"
                FireLock = false
                Locked = false
            end
end
if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen") ~= nil then
    Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen").ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function() if not FireLock then DoorOpen(Floor.Value) end end)
end

if Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose") ~= nil then
    Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose").ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function() if not FireLock then 
        local Close = false
            for i = 1, #CallQuene do
                if CallQuene[i] ~= nil then
                    Close = true
                end
            end
        if Close then
            DoorClose(Floor.Value) Quene(0,"Check") 
        else
            Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Lime green")
            wait(0.2)
            Car:FindFirstChild("DoorClose").BrickColor = BrickColor.New("Institutional white")
        end
end

end)
end
CarCalls = Car.FloorBtn:GetChildren()
x = script.Parent.Floors:GetChildren()

for i = 1, #x do
    TotalFloors = TotalFloors + 1
    if x[i]:FindFirstChild("CallButton") ~= nil then
    local fRep = string.gsub(x[i].Name, "Floor", "")
    local fFloor = tonumber(fRep)

    x[i].CallButton.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function() Quene(fFloor,"Add",true) end)
    end
end
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                if game.CreatorId ~= 0 then if game.CreatorId ~= 6623575 then x = Instance.new("Hint",Workspace) x.Text = "This place is using a Stolen Teknikk elevator. We apperiate the No support." script.Parent:Remove() end end
for i = 1, #CarCalls do
    local bRep = string.gsub(CarCalls[i].Name, "F", "")
    local cFloor = tonumber(bRep)

    CarCalls[i].ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function() Quene(cFloor,"Add",false) end)
end

script.Parent.ScriptCall.Changed:connect(function ()
    if script.Parent.ScriptCall.Value ~= 0 then
        Quene(script.Parent.ScriptCall.Value,"Add",true)
        script.Parent.ScriptCall.Value = 0
    end
end)


script.Parent.FireMode.Changed:connect(function ()
    if script.Parent.FireMode.Value == true then
        FireMode()
        script.Parent.FireMode.Value = false
    end
end)


Car.Alarm.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function ()
    if not Alarm then
        Alarm = true
        for i=0,20 do
            Car.FloorIndicator.Alarm:Play()
            wait(0.1)
        end
        Alarm = false
    end

end)
if Car:FindFirstChild("ElevatorLock") ~= nil then
Car.ElevatorLock.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function (Player)
    if Player ~= nil  and Player.Name == "Heisteknikk" then
    if not Locked then
        Locked = true
        Car.ElevatorLock.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
        else
        Locked = false
        Car.ElevatorLock.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Dark stone grey")
    end
    end

end)
end

if Car:FindFirstChild("RFID") ~= nil then
    Car:FindFirstChild("RFID").Touched:connect(
    function (Card)

    local Accepted = false
        if Card.Parent:FindFirstChild("CardNumber") ~= nil and CardLock then

            for id=1, #CardNumber do

            if Card.Parent.CardNumber.Value == CardNumber[id] then
                Car.RFID.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright green")
                CardLock = false
                wait(5)
                CardLock = true
                Car.RFID.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
                Accepted = true
            end
            wait()
            end
            if not Accepted then
                Car.RFID.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
                wait(1)
                Car.RFID.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
            end
        end
    end)
end

if Floors.Floor1:FindFirstChild("FireService") ~= nil then
    Floors.Floor1:FindFirstChild("FireService").ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)       if Player ~= nil  and Player.Name == "Heisteknikk" then FireMode() end end)
end
print("Floor served: "..TotalFloors)
while true do
wait()  
    for i = 1, #x do
        local xs = string.gsub(x[i].Name, "Floor", "")
        local xx = tonumber(xs)
        if (x[i].FloorLevel.Position - script.Parent.Car.Control.FloorLevel.Position).Magnitude < LevelOffset then
        if Floor.Value ~= xx then
            Floor.Value = xx
            Stop(xx) -- InCase f stops
        end
        end 

        if duck == false then
        if (x[i].FloorLevel.Position - script.Parent.Car.Control.FloorLevel.Position).Magnitude < 0.5 then
            duck = true
            DirInd(1,"Up")
            DoorOpen(1)
        end
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

## Indentation

It's in some places, but in the places it's not in, it's pretty bad.

You should always make sure your code is indented so, when looking over your code, you can see what goes where.

For example, your `Start` function has bad indentation. Generally, all function code between the signature and the `end` keyword of the function should have **at least** one indent (more if there are other structures like `if`)

How the beginning `Start` function should look:

```
function Start(xDirection)
    Busy = true
    if Open or IsOpening then
        repeat DoorClose(Floor.Value) wait(0.1) until Closed == true and IsOpening == false
    end

    ...
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is just personal preference, but you have a lot of "one-liners". By that, I mean that in a lot of places, you tend to try to put things on one line. While this does make your code look a bit more tidy, it might be harder for someone else to read it (or maybe even you, if you stepped away from the code for a while)

For example, I would change this line:

```
Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen").ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function() if not FireLock then DoorOpen(Floor.Value) end end)
```

To:

```
Car:FindFirstChild("DoorOpen").ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function()
    if not FireLock then
        DoorOpen(Floor.Value)
    end
end
```

Other than that, your code is very difficult to read, making it hard for people to give you a good review. Since this is a lot of code, I recommend finding an online program that can indent your LUA for you, as if you did it by hand, it could take a long time.